# How to call struct from separate function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct workers{
    int ID;
    string name;
    string lastname;
    int date;
};

bool check_ID(workers *people, workers &guy);
void check_something(workers *people, workers &guy, int& i);

int main()
{
    workers people[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> people[i].ID;
        cin >> people[i].name;
        cin >> people[i].lastname;
        cin >> people[i].date;
        if(check_ID(people, people[i]) == true)
            cout << "True" << endl;
        else
            cout << "False" << endl;
        check_something(people, people[i], i);
    }
    return 0;
}

bool check_ID(workers *people, workers &guy){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(people[i].ID == guy.ID)
            return true;
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

void check_something(workers *people, workers &guy, int& i){
    check_ID(people, guy[i]);
}
```

This is the code I have, it's not very good example, but I quickly wrote it to represent my problem I have because my project is kinda too big. So basically, I want to call struct from a different function and I'm getting this error:
`error: no match for 'operator[]' in guy[i]` on this line :
`check_ID(people, guy[i]);` in the function `check_something`.

Comment: what's the purpose of guy[i]? if you want to be able to apply subscript operator to `struct workers`, of course you need to define it, the compiler's making it very clear.

Comment: What do you want/expect `check_something` to do?

Comment: My fault.. I forgot void returns nothing, it seems to work now! :-) Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `main`, `people` is an array. You access the `i`th element of it `people[i]` and try to pass it to `check_something` in the position of function-local variable `guy`. You then try to dereference `guy` - which is not an array, but a single object instance.

```
int main()
{
    workers people[5];  // <-- array
```

...

```
    check_something(people /* <-- people */, people[i] /* <-- guy */, i /* <-- i */);
```

vs

```
void check_something(workers *people, workers &guy, int& i){
    check_ID(people, guy[i] /* <-- array access on single instance*/);
```

You actually passed the array in the first argument, people. You don't need "guy" here, because it is `people[i]`, isn't it? So you could do:

```
void check_something(workers *people, int& i){
    worker& guy = people[i];
    check_ID(people, guy);
```

or just

```
void check_something(workers *people, int& i){
    check_ID(people, people[i]);
```

or

would work, or you could just pass

```
void check_something(workers* people, workers& guy) {
    check_id(people, guy);
}
```

---- EDIT ----

You also have a python-like bug in your check_ID function.

```
   if(people[i].ID == guy.ID)
        return true;
        break;
```

In Python, this says:

```
if people[i].ID == guy.ID:
    return True

break
```

What you want is

```
if ( people[i].ID == guy.ID ) {
    return true;
    break;
}
```

or just

```
if ( people[i].ID == guy.ID )
    return true;
```

(since the return is going to exit the function, there's no point in also saying break afterwards)

Comment: I declared `workers guy = people[i];` and when I call the function with `check_ID(people, guy)`, It still does nothing (doesn't do its function). Why is that? I also tried `people[i]` as second reference and it still doesn't output anything.

Comment: `workers guy = people[i]` makes a copy of `people[i]` into a temporary, local variable called `guy`.

Comment: Also, your 'check_ID' function is broken because you have a 'break' that always executes.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the check_ID/return/break thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I really should start using {} everywhere, even if it's one line code I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`workers` does not have an overloaded subscript operator, nor is `guy` an array. Therefore you cannot call `[]` on it. Either create an array or delete `[i]` after `guy`.

```
check_ID(people, guy); //delete [i]
```

Comment: I did try with guy, but it does nothing.. it goes through the function, does the call to check_ID, but the check_ID does nothing, I guess because the guy has no value or something?

Answer (score 0):

Guy is a reference, not a pointer. You cannot use the operator[] on a reference.